# Rails: How to import JS/CSS from "vendor/plugins/" directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to use [the jQuery UI Datepicker plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) in my Rails 3 application.

I thought to put it in `vendor/plugins/` directory. (Is there a better place ?)

I tried to import the JS file like that:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag '/vendor/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.9-datepicker/js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js' %>
```

but it does not recognize the path.

How should I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serve the javascripts, they will need to be placed in public/

If you place the file itself in public/javascripts/ it can be referenced with:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js' %>
```

Don't forget to include Jquery and JqueryUI javascripts for this JS plugin to work.

Comment: So what you say is that all JS and CSS files that I want to use **MUST** be in the `public` directory ?

Comment: Yes exactly. All static content is referenced with the public directory as it's base.

Comment: [This has changed in Rails 3.1.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562140/rails-3-1-serving-images-from-vendor-assets-images)

Comment: Yes, this answer is incorrect. You probably want it in `assets/javascripts`.