# Rails 3.1 serving images from vendor/assets/images

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I am trying to put some external images (used by a jQuery plugin) to vendor/assets/images in my Rails 3.1 app. Problem is that when I try something like:

```
<%= image_tag "ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png" %>
```

I get an error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/assets/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png"
```

I checked my Rails.application.config.assets.paths and it list these dirs:

```
..../app/assets/images
..../app/assets/javascripts
..../app/assets/stylesheets
..../vendor/assets/images
..../vendor/assets/stylesheets
..../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@mygems/gems/jquery-rails-1.0.9/vendor/assets/javascripts
```

As you can see /vendor/assets/images is listed there. If I put my image to app/assets/images everything works.

I thought that new asset pipeline was supposed to go through all assets dirs and serve requested file wherever it finds it.

Does anyone knows what's the problem here?

Comment: sorry, not exactly helping your problem, but how do you see the Rails.application.config.assets.paths ?

Comment: @martin: you can see it in console

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but are your jqueryui assets in the images directory? Mine are in the image directory, and then in their own subdirectory to preserve the CSS paths jqueryui's theme maker generates.

Comment: Having the same problem, feels like a bug to me.

Comment: I'm sure you have tried it already, but just in case: I was having the same problem even after moving the assets to the right location, modifying jQuery UI CSS image paths and making sure everything was correct. Restarting the dev server solved it in the end. Seems Sprockets needs to restart to get new assets.

Comment: +1 to @TomásArribas - the CSS file has `images/` as part of its path. removing that was the cure for me

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I had to restart my rails server after creating the `vendor/assets/images` directory. Before this, I was seeing the same error as you ("No route matches [GET]").

My guess is that the rails server does not check these directories if they did not exist when it was first started. When you open a rails console to diagnose the issue, you get a new instance of rails which knows about the directory, which only adds to the confusion.

Comment: Using Pow (and powder gem) I just tried a 'powder restart' with no luck. Then I tried 'powder down' and 'powder up' and finally Rails.application.config.assets.paths included vendor/assets/images.

Comment: If you're using pow, just `touch tmp/restart.txt` in your console to restart the individual app. No need to bring the whole server down.

Answer (score 22):

If you are using a jQuery UI Theme Roller theme then the problem might be that in the jquery-ui css file the images are referenced within a sub folder 'images'.

I.e. you either have to put your images in a folder `'./app/assets/images/images'` or you have to edit the jquery-ui css file and remove the 'images/' folder prefix.

Comment: It's somewhat confusing that you might see `GET http://example.com/assets/images/darrowleft.gif 404 (Not Found)` in a javascript console and you have that image in `vendor/assets/images`. However, you*should* see `http://example.com/assets/darrowleft.gif` for the URL.  To see `http://example.com/assets/images/darrowleft.gif` you have to put that image in `vendor/assets/images/images` as @woelfle explained.  Doing so will save you the hassle of having to modify paths in vendored CSS files.

Comment: Putting the images in yet another folder called images seems weird, but worked for me on rails 3.1.3. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, George, that was the missing piece of the puzzle for me!

Answer (score 9):

The asset pipeline is described in this rails guide by Ryan Bigg (draft status at the moment).

http://ryanbigg.com/guides/asset_pipeline.html and http://ryanbigg.com/2011/06/sprocket-asset-tags-internals/ for the references.

According to this, your example should work.

Extract:

> Assets can be placed inside an application in one of three locations: app/assets, lib/assets or vendor/assets.
>
> app/assets is for assets that are owned by the application, such as custom images, javascript files or stylesheets.
>
> lib/assets is for your own libraries’ code that doesn’t really fit into the scope of the application or those libraries which are shared across applications.
>
> vendor/assets is for assets that are owned by outside entities, such as code for JavaScript plugins.
>
> Any subdirectory that exists within these three locations will be added to the search path for Sprockets (visible by calling Rails.application.config.assets.paths in a console). When an asset is requested, these paths will be looked through to see if they contain an asset matching the name specified. Once an asset has been found, it’s processed by Sprockets and then served up.

I have tested with an example in my app and the same syntax as yours works. Maybe you have a typo in the name of your asset.

For Martin: search path for Sprockets is visible by calling Rails.application.config.assets.paths in a console.

Comment: Yes, I've read that. That's why I think it should work. Maybe it's a bug.

Comment: For me it does work. Did you try to rename your asset as a test ?

Comment: this is a recurring problem in all my apps i build in Rails 3

Comment: Only app/assets is searched for images (at least in Rails 4). There is some config to change that here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14195512/161815

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should create another folder in /assets/images. You make a name 'images' and then you just copy all jquery-ui image and paste on folder 'images' that you create before. Hopefully this will help you.