# rails 4 asset pipeline vendor assets images are not being precompiled

Tags: asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using rails 4 & ruby 1.9.3 for my application and `fancybox2-rails` gem, but there's a general problem with asset pipeline. If I run `rake task` for precompile, then everything is fine except for images in `vendor/assets/images` and `../gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/fancybox2-rails-0.2.1/vendor/assets/images`. Images from these two folders are not being precompiled and eventually I have a problem with dead links to non-existing images. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It seems like images are included by default only from app/assets folder. So the solution is to add this line to config/application.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)
```

Comment: This is working for me, but this setting *should* go into the config/environments/production.rb file. However, this is currently broken in rails 4.0.0.beta1 (see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9572 and https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/pull/36)

Comment: I initially had 2 images that wouldn't load, fancybox_loading.gif and fancybox_overlay.png, this fixed overlay.png but loading.gif still doesn't work.

Comment: Put it in production.rb, but it did not help upon deploy. No fancybox images present in the compiled assets.

Comment: This does not have a vendor/assets link? It does not seem to work for me.

Comment: i thought vendor directory is now excluded from pre-compile process?

Answer (score 9):

It sounds Sporker can't autoload images from vendor/assets/images.

> 2.2 Asset Organization
>   Pipeline assets can be placed inside an application in one of three locations: app/assets, lib/assets or vendor/assets.
>
> app/assets is for assets that are owned by the application, such as custom images, JavaScript files or stylesheets.
>
> lib/assets is for your own libraries' code that doesn't really fit into the scope of the application or those libraries which are shared across applications.
>
> vendor/assets is for assets that are owned by outside entities, such as code for JavaScript plugins and CSS frameworks

From the description come from [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), I don't think they ignored vendor/assets/images with no intention.

So I just added the follow line:

```
#config/application.rb
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "images")
```

And, I solved my problem.
I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 6):

For my Rails 4.2.x project, I just moved the vendor images to `vendor/assets/images` and added this to `application.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(vendor/assets/images/*)
```

Works fine on development and production.

Comment: This worked on my Rails 5 application, so now `image_tag('image.png')` is returning the right image