# Rails4 issue with serving vendor assets (images)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I recently upgraded to Rails4 and I have issues with precompiling image assets in the vendor folder. I know that vendor/assets folder was removed from compiling by default.

I added vendor/assets/* folder to assets.precompile configuration, which gets assets precompiled, but my app won't display the images that are under vendor/assets/images folder. It appears that image paths in that folder are rendered on production, but with a wrong hash postfix.

```
config.assets.precompile += [ 'themes/*', 'jquery.fancybox.css', 'vendor/assets/*' ]
```

The Rails4 documentation for handling this issue is really poor. I don't want to move files from vendor/assets to app/assets as I like to have my and foreign files separated.

My question is: what should I do to fix serving vendor images on production?

Thanks for help

Comment: Please see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34532668/3102766) on a similar question.

Answer (score 5):

Since version 4 `vendor` and `lib` directories are not included in the asset pipeline by default. If you'd like to precompile assets in those directories , you should extend the asset path like this:

(in your `application.rb`):

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "images")
```

Comment: Is it good practice to do this, or should you move them to the app/assets directory?

Comment: The good practice is to keep the external code (for example - from purchased themes) in `vendor` directory. You can move the assets to `app/assets` too, but watch out not to mess the `assets` directory. There could be duplication of some filenames.

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "images")`?

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had to add the folder to my precompile list.

Answer (score 2):

It says in the docs (extract from rails guides for rails ):

vendor/assets is for assets that are owned by outside entities, such as code for JavaScript plugins and CSS frameworks. **Keep in mind that third party code with references to other files also processed by the asset Pipeline (images, stylesheets, etc.), will need to be rewritten to use helpers like asset_path**.

So all the css files you put in vendor that reference other fonts and/or images need to be manually edited to include asset pipeline helper methods whenever they reference another resource. For example:

```
.my-class { background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'image.png' %>) }

.logo { background: url(<%= asset_data_uri 'logo.png' %>) }
```

There are also font_path, image_path and audio_path, note that in SASS you just use the hypened versions (image-path, audio-path...)

Comment: This was the only way it worked. Renaming asset to css.erb and included the tags for the asset pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `vendor/assets/**/*`?

```
config.assets.precompile += [ 'themes/*', 'jquery.fancybox.css', 'vendor/assets/**/*' ]
```