# How to precompile images to public/assets/images

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, image, heroku

I am using jquery-ui which comes with quite a few images. I have them in `public/assets/images`. Following the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization I'd like to have them in `vendor/assets/images`. This would also avoid deleting them with `$ rake assets:clobber`.

But when - following [Using a jQuery UI Theme with Rails 4 - No Images being served](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356434/using-a-jquery-ui-theme-with-rails-4-no-images-being-served) - I put them in `vendor/assets/images` and precompile, they end up in `public/assets` which makes this folder quite messy. I want them precompiled to `public/assets/images`.

I have not found a solution. Is this something trivial that I am missing or is this something unusual to want? Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Rails `rake assets:precompile` command will precompile all assets into static files and will be kept in public/assets only by default. If you want it in a custom folder:

Please refer: http://makandracards.com/makandra/8951-rails-asset-pipeline-how-to-organize-stylesheets-in-sub-folders

i.e., as per the link,

if you want all the images to be precompiled and stored in `'/public/assets/images'`, you need to create them under `'vendor/assets/images/images'` folder.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I can't see the configuration of Rails to precompile images to public/assets/images in that article. Did I miss it?