# Rails 4 Asset Pipeline With Lib and Vendor Folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, precompile

I was reading the documentation on Rails 4 and the Asset Pipeline when I got tripped up by this line:

> If you are upgrading from Rails 3, please take into account that assets under lib/assets or vendor/assets are available for inclusion via the application manifests but no longer part of the precompile array

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization

What is the difference between being available for inclusion via the application manifest and being part of the precompile array? Does this mean that if I were to have a javascript file `lib/vendor/cool_plugin.js` I would get a 404 when I went to production even if I had `//require cool_plugin` in `application.js`?

Answer (score 3):

From http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html:

> In Rails 4.0, precompiling assets no longer automatically copies
>   non-JS/CSS assets from vendor/assets and lib/assets. Rails application
>   and engine developers should put these assets in app/assets or
>   configure config.assets.precompile.

so I believe you need to explicitly reference your vendor assets for them to get picked up during precompilation on production:

```
# production.rb
config.assets.precompile += %w( cool_plugin.js )
```

Comment: I was interpreting non-JS/CSS to be images. I would read the quote you brought over to mean that `cool_plugin.js` would be handled automatically because it is a JS file.  Am I misreading that?

Comment: I just tested this out with a test file placed in `/lib/assets/stylesheets/test.css.scss` and I had to explicitly add it to the `config.assets.precompile` (as `test.css`) for it to work on production. `require test` in `application.css` was not enough.

Comment: If you ended up here because you have images in vendor/assets that aren't precompiling, see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194752/rails-4-asset-pipeline-vendor-assets-images-are-not-being-precompiled?rq=1